# How can I insert into the middle of a list in ELisp?

Tags: list, emacs, lisp, elisp

I have the following data structure as an ELisp variable (`ispell-tex-skip-alists`):

```
((("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 2)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 0)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ("---" . "---"))
 (("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 0)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 2)
  ("env1" . "endenv1")
  ("env2" . "endenv2")))
```

I can isolate the part of the list I need with with `cddadr`,
  but I need to add an element to this list:

```
((("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 2)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 0)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
  ("---" . "---"))
 (("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 0)
  ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 2)
  ("env1" . "endenv1")
  ("env2" . "endenv2")
  ("env3" . "endenv3")))
```

I have tried `add-to-list`, but obviously I need a symbol name for the `cddadr` part of the list (which I could technically optimize to `cadr`) for `add-to-list` to work.

How might I achieve the result I need?

---

Best attempt:

```
(defun LaTeX-ispell-skip-environment (env &optional star)
  (let ((start (concat "%s" (if star "\\*?")))
    (end   (concat "\\\\end[    \n]*{[  \n]*%s" (if star "\\*?") "[     \n]*}")))
    (let ((env-list (cddadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
      (setcdr (last env-list)
          (cons (format start env)
            (format end env))))))
```

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question stated in the title more generically, here is a function which inserts an element in the n-th position of a list:

```lisp
(defun insert-into-list (list el n)
  "Insert into list LIST an element EL at index N.

If N is 0, EL is inserted before the first element.

The resulting list is returned.  As the list contents is mutated
in-place, the old list reference does not remain valid."
  (let* ((padded-list (cons nil list))
         (c (nthcdr n padded-list)))
    (setcdr c (cons el (cdr c)))
    (cdr padded-list)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are missing a `list` in your approach:

```lisp
(defun LaTeX-ispell-skip-environment (env &optional star)
  (let ((start (concat "%s" (if star "\\*?")))
    (end   (concat "\\\\end[    \n]*{[  \n]*%s" (if star "\\*?") "[     \n]*}")))
    (let ((env-list (cddadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
      (setcdr (last env-list)
              (list 
               (cons (format start env)
                     (format end env)))))))
```

In your version the structure of the relevant list changes. Before the modification it is a list of conses. After the modification it is a mixed list. Most of the entries are conses but the last car is a string and the last cdr is also a string.

Alternatively to `setcdr` and `last`, you could use `nconc`:

```lisp
(defun LaTeX-ispell-skip-environment (env &optional star)
  (let ((start (concat "%s" (if star "\\*?")))
    (end   (concat "\\\\end[    \n]*{[  \n]*%s" (if star "\\*?") "[     \n]*}")))
    (let ((env-list (cddadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
      (nconc env-list
             (list 
              (cons (format start env)
                    (format end env)))))))
```

---

### Test

There follows a test. To make comparison with the wanted result from the original posting possible I replaced `"\\\\end[    \n]*{[  \n]*%s"` by `"end%s"` and `"[     \n]*}"` by `""` in `LaTeX-ispell-skip-environment`. At the end of the `progn` the result of `(LaTeX-ispell-skip-environment "env3")` is tested with `equal` against the wanted result. The test returns `t`.

```lisp
(progn
  (defun LaTeX-ispell-skip-environment (env &optional star)
    (let ((start (concat "%s" (if star "\\*?")))
      (end   (concat "end%s" (if star "\\*?") "")))
      (let ((env-list (cddadr ispell-tex-skip-alists)))
    (setcdr (last env-list)
        (list 
         (cons (format start env)
               (format end env)))))))

  (setq ispell-tex-skip-alists
    '((("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 2)
       ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
       ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
       ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
       ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 0)
       ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
       ("---" . "---"))
      (("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 0)
       ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 2)
       ("env1" . "endenv1")
       ("env2" . "endenv2"))))

  (LaTeX-ispell-skip-environment "env3")

  (equal ispell-tex-skip-alists
     '((("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 2)
        ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
        ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
        ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
        ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 0)
        ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end)
        ("---" . "---"))
       (("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 0)
        ("---" ispell-tex-arg-end 2)
        ("env1" . "endenv1")
        ("env2" . "endenv2")
        ("env3" . "endenv3")))))
```

Comment: I tried the former, but it wanted to interpret the list as a function call. I've yet to try the former. (Unfortunately this might take a day or two; my computer is unresponsive and I must wait for the battery to run down so that osx saves the session.)

Comment: Or even `append`. ;-)  Do you need to share (i.e., modify) the list structure?  If not then don't use `setc[ad]r` or `nconc`.  And even if you do need that, you can often help yourself by testing parts of the code initially using, say, `append` instead of `nconc`.

Comment: @Drew the function does need such a side-effect.  The entire rest of the code works—it's just the addition that eludes me.

Comment: @SeanAllred The code is tested and works. Maybe, you missed the explicit `list` form in your code.

Comment: @Drew In this case `nconc` works exclusively by side-effect. A version with `append` is more complicated since `append` returns a copy without side-effects. One would have a problem with `nconc` if the code should also be able to create a new list starting from `nil`. But this is not the case in the original posting.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for testing it—my computer is still out-of-order but it should be up by tomorrow.  Using `nconc` does seem to be the best option here, then; the alist will (*should*) never start from `nil`. It's easy to add a `don't do this` case-check at any rate.

Comment: @Tobias *Of course* `nconc` performs side effects. The point is to get the basic structure right first (e.g. missing `list`), without introducing structure mod at the same time. If having trouble understanding what structure to use and how to build it, you don't need to add the difficulty of understanding effects of structure change. Its about getting the list correct first. You can remove destructive operations to test parts of code. If modification is needed in the end then reintroduce it. I am not saying that the complete code will work the same with `nconc` replaced by `append` etc.

Comment: I have added a test that shows that the basic structure is right. Thereby, "right" means that `LaTeX-ispell-skip-environment` delivers the wanted result given in the original posting. To make a direct comparison possible only the strings in `LaTeX-ispell-skip-environment` had to be adjusted.